# How do you get IAM credentials using Amplify Auth?

Tags: aws-amplify

I am trying to get IAM credentials using Amplify ^5.0.7.  I am able to successfully log in and get OpenID tokens:

```js
Auth.signIn({
    username: user,
    password: password
})
.then((u: CognitoUser) => {
    console.log("User", u);
    console.log("Credentials", Auth.Credentials);
    console.log("Essential credentials", Auth.essentialCredentials(Auth.Credentials));
    return Auth.currentSession();
}).then((data: CognitoUserSession) => {
     console.log("Current session", data);
     return Auth.essentialCredentials(Auth.currentCredentials())
}).then((c: ICredentials) => {
    console.log("Credentials", c);
})
```

That successfully signs in, and gets a current session that has id, access, and refresh tokens.  The problem is that there are no Credentials.  currentCredentials() returns an ICredentials object, but its fields are all undefined.  I think those should map to temporary IAM credentials.

The user I'm testing against belongs to exactly one group, and that group has an IAM role assigned to it.

Am I missing a step to request the temporary IAM credentials?  I am not using amplify on the backend.  I'm really using Amplify Auth because it deals with SRP for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, and it was simpler than I thought.  I want to post what I did to fix it, in case anybody else has the same problem.

What I did was basically correct, except you don't need to get the session first.

```js
Auth.signIn({
    username: userInput,
    password: passwordInput
})
.then((u: CognitoUser) => {
    console.log("Auth.credentials", Auth.Credentials)
    return Auth.currentCredentials()
}).then((currentCredentials: ICredentials) => {
    console.log("Essential credentials", Auth.essentialCredentials(currentCredentials))
})
```

There was not really a "code" trick to getting it to work.  The real problem was that I was not careful enough about how I was setting up Cognito.  To do this, you need both a user pool AND an identity pool.  The identity pool points back toward the user pool.  I had done that, but I wasn't setting Amplify up correctly.  The way that works is:

```js
Amplify.configure({
     Auth: {
        mandatorySignIn: true,
        region: 'us-east-1',
        userPoolId: 'us-east-1_CX1xxxxxx',
        userPoolWebClientId: '5eo394ojo1gvdm6cbxxxxxxxxxs',
        identityPoolId: 'us-east-1:f69259b2-ff84-4731-b80c-xf421-xxxx'
    }
});
```

if you don't care about the IAM credentials, you don't seem to need the identity pool nor do you need to specify its ID.  If you leave them out, you just get an empty Credentials back.

So Amplify does everything.  I'm new to Amplify, and it's a lot less work then dealing with SRP directly.